# Reactive v-model with debounce function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a reusable component `SearchInput` from which I pass data from an input. But I also use the `debounce` function. If I place `debounce` in a `SearchInput`, then there will be a delay before the data changes. If the `debounce` is placed in the **parent** component, then everything works without delay. How can I make it so that I don't have to write a `debounce` function in every parent component?

`SearchInput` component with the following code:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
interface IProps {
    searchString?: string;
}

const emit = defineEmits<{
    handleSearch: [value: string];
}>();

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<IProps>(), {
    searchString: ''
});

const inputValue = computed({
    get(): string {
        return props.searchString;
    },
    set(value: string) {
        emit('handleSearch', value);
    }
});
</script>

<template>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input v-model="inputValue" class="input" placeholder="Type the name of book or author...">
        <img class="icon" src="@/assets/images/icons/MAGNIFYING_GLASS.svg" alt="search">
    </div>
</template>
```

And I have perent component `ToolBar`:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import SearchInput from '@/components/UI/SearchInput.vue';

interface IProps {
    searchString?: string
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<IProps>(), {
    searchString: ''
});

const route = useRoute();
const router = useRouter();

let searchValue = ref<string>(props.searchString);

const handleSearch = (value: string) => {
    const timeoutId: number = window.setTimeout(() => {}, 0);

    for (let id: number = timeoutId; id >= 0; id -= 1) {
        window.clearTimeout(id);
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
        if (value.length < 3) {
            router.push({});
            return;
        }

        router.push({ query: { search: value } });
    }, 1000);
};

watch(route, () => {
    const routeQuery = route.query.search;

    if (typeof routeQuery === 'string') {
        searchValue.value = routeQuery;
    } else {
        searchValue.value = '';
    }
}, {immediate: true});
</script>

<template>
    <div class="search-input">
        <search-input
            :search-string="searchValue"
            @handle-search="handleSearch"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="toolbar">
        <div v-show="searchValue" class="toolbar__search">
            Results “<span>{{ searchValue }}</span>”
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this ```for (let id: number = timeoutId; id >= 0; id -= 1) {
        window.clearTimeout(id);
    }```

Answer (score 0):

I think your handleSearch function should be something closer to this.

```
const handleSearch = (value: string) => {
    // Test to see if a countdown is already going.
    // Clear it if it does exist
    if(window.timeoutId){
       window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }

    // Start a new countdown and store the id globally 
    window.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        if (value.length < 3) {
            router.push({});
            return;
        }

        router.push({ query: { search: value } });
    }, 1000);
};
```

Comment: It works. And my previous solution worked too. I want to move this from ``ToolBar`` to input so I don't have to write this every time I use the component

Comment: @Maks Have you tried moving this code into your computed set() function?

Answer (score 0):

We have incorporated [VueUse](https://vueuse.org) into most of our Vue projects. It's fast, compact, and is actively developed. It offers debounce and throttling for functions (and a few other scenarios for refs). In your case, I would try [`useDebounceFn()`](https://vueuse.org/shared/useDebounceFn/) which would look like this:

```js
import {useDebounceFn} from '@vueuse/core';

const handleSearch = (value: string) => {
  if (value.length < 3) {
    router.push({});
    return;
  }

  router.push({ query: { search: value } });
};

const debouncedSearchHandler = useDebounceFn(handleSearch, 1000);
```

You can then use `debouncedSearchHandler` as the handler for the `@handle-search` event.

With this implementation, the `handleSearch` function is more readable because it focuses on the work at hand, and not on debouncing.

You might also check out [`watchDebounced()`](https://vueuse.org/shared/watchDebounced/#watchdebounced) and [`refDebounced()`](https://vueuse.org/shared/refDebounced/#refdebounced) in case that gives you some other implementation ideas. There are throttle variants as well.